# Which is a better folder name to use in my URL?

Tags: seo, url, google-search, google-ranking, folder

We are putting together a knowledge base with various self service articles as well as technical documentation for an opensource application we're building.

We obviously want the articles to be easily found by our users via Google.

We have decided against a sub domain, so now the question lies in 1 thing:

**The actual word we use as the folder name**

1. Which is better for SEO as a folder name for the knowledge base?

example.com/knowledgebase
or

example.com/documentation
or

exampe.com/articles
or

is there a better descriptive word that will help users find this information?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Or depends. Both those answers are correct.

Some would even think FAQ belongs. I'm creating a site where the link is "Learn". What will your audience understand? That's for researching. Ask people questions.

Comment: I like this answer because as you said- it is all about the audience!